# Can two objects be in the exact same state and yet behave differently?

Tags: classical-mechanics, particle-physics

Can two objects be in the very exact same physical/atomic state yet behave differently?

The only thing I could think of is motion (two objects could be strictly identical down to the atomic level, yet one could be moving differently from the other). Are there others?

What I mean by state is "everything you could possibly observe about the object itself isolated from its environment", and by behaviour I mean "everything you could observe about the object in its environment".

So to my understanding 2 tennis balls could be in the very exact same state (have the same shape, color, atom composition, etc.), yet move differently. Is this true, and are there other examples of such differences?

Comment: This seems like it depends entirely on how you choose to define "state".  For example, I would say that two objects moving relative to one another are in a different state of motion, since you can define different velocities for each relative to the same reference points.

Comment: yes, too much ambiguities here in question. If ALL properties of those objects are the same - how you would differentiate between those two ? Maybe it's just one object ? At least one property need to be different to call those "different objects",- position, speed, shape, spin, etc. And if _something_ differs - it's NOT same state technically

Comment: Yes . When you use the term "atomic" you are in the quantum mechanics framework, and there only probability predictions can be made, where  by definition of probability, they behave differently even with the same boundary conditions.Once you put motion in the problem, every two objects  can behave  differently since no two macroscopic objects can be at the same (x,y,z,t).Even the scattering of two billiard balls has a classical probability distribution  because "exact" bounds have a limit, due to the surface of the balls not being uniform and the uncertainty in the force applied

Comment: The distinction between properties that are "isolated from its environment" and those that aren't isn't currently well-defined, and needs to be specific. For example, the shape of a tennis ball depends on the pressure of its environment (a high enough pressure will dent the tennis ball, and a low enough pressure may cause it to bulge), and the "color" (which I'm taking to mean "the visible light-range spectrum") of the tennis ball depends on the temperature of its environment, since the tennis ball emits temperature-dependent blackbody radiation.

Comment: @probably_someone "Isolated from its environment" means that you know nothing about the environment, you can just observe the system itself. In your case, you can observe the ball being pressured or hot.

Comment: @Skeptron Ok, then in that case, things like position and momentum qualify as properties that are "isolated from the environment"; you can measure them regardless of the presence or absence of any other objects, and they are properties of the ball itself. So I still don't quite understand your definition of "state" and why it excludes position and momentum.